# Guess the erased text on this bottom bracket

Tags: bottom-bracket

I'm trying to keep my old mountain-bike alive, it's been so good to me. I acquired the proper tools to remove the crank and, well I guess I have two questions:

- There was a lot of rust and water in there - picture is representative. Would you attempt to clean it and re-insert it, or should I not - in your opinion - bother?
- If I were to purchase a new one, which should I get? The text has been worn off and I'm not experienced enough to know which replacement crank I should get. I gather it's a 68 millimetre body-width, but the other digits and letters elude me - please help. Thanks so much in advance.

[image]

Comment: “There was a lot of rust and water in there” Check the inside of the frame while you are at it. Especially the welds around the bottom bracket and chainstays.

Answer (score 8):

Looks like a CHIN HAUR bottom bracket to me. Text would most likely be:
CH52-68
122L-EN
BC1.37x24T

68 MM width was pretty standard, so that is probably right. The 24T refers to the thread per inch and is also very common. I believe the 122L-EN means the spindle length is 122 MM.

If you are just trying to salvage the bike, you could certainly overhaul it, replace the likely sealed bearings (I don't have experience with this brand so I don't know if it uses loose bearings or not), chase the threads and reinstall it.

Then again you could likely find a new bottom bracket like a Shimano BB-UN300 for around $20-25 USD or less, and that would give you a fresh start and smooth spin.

Both options assume you are going to put the existing crankset back on the bike. If you are planning on switching up the crankset, then the determining factor is whether or not the new crankset is compatible with the square-taper bottom bracket, or if it uses something like ISIS Splined or Shimano Octalink splined spindles.

Image for reference: [CHIN HAUR CH52-68](https://imgur.com/N8OLIkU)

Comment: I completely agree; that's exactly where I ended up.

Comment: @morten-nørgaard If you found this answer to be helpful/correct, please follow the StackExchange convention and mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

What bike did that come off of? I'm guessing that's standards JIS square taper. You can easily get a replacement and it won't cost you much. You're likely correct that the BB shell is 68 mm wide. The main thing is to get the spindle length correct. Take it to a shop and they'll be able to measure it properly.

However, the bearings still spin smoothly and there not any axial or radial play in them, I'd clean everything, regrease the threads, and reinstall it.